# Can I use dry concrete mix to set a post in saturated soil?

Tags: concrete

How dry does the ground need to be in order to use postcret? I'm in norcal and we've had tons of rain. The ground is real saturated at 1 1/2 to 2ft.

Answer (score 1):

You should not put dry concrete mix into a hole.   The wetness is really not the big thing it is the fact that you may not mix it properly meaning you will have pockets of dust as things settle.   These small pockets of unmixed mix will make the concrete extremely weak and will crack or crumble apart - "a buddy had this issue one time" haha.

You mix the concrete as normal (maybe shy on the side of drier mix) and simply dump it in the hole. It will displace the water since it is heavier. I have also dammed up holes and pumped out the water while filling - this just takes a few minutes a hole and keeps the hole integrity better and keeps from getting concrete slopped everywhere.

For wet conditions I use Quickcrete fast setting. It won't cure/set in 40 mins under water but it does harden enough to hold a post and move on.   Others may have personal favorites for wet conditions but I can say that using the right type is a big deal.

Comment: How do you pump it out?

Comment: @aparente001 - a water pump or wet vac.   Or you can just use a hose if you can get suction.

Answer (score 0):

Dry enough that there is no standing water after "sprinkling" it on the ground. (It's not a structural product, (no compressive strength,) so it's not critical to structural performance.

Comment: I have put in posts with standing water in the hole and added the mix dry. I do usually over fill but it has worked well.

Comment: @EdBeal   I doubt if you can find any agency, association, (Portland cement association), etc. that would "recommend" pouring into water is "best practices."

Comment: I believe if putting the mix in the hole dry or not pre mixed some water in the hole first works better than adding water after filling the hole with the mix. Yes the water is supposed to be potable but if there is high ground water getting the hole dry is not realistic. I have put in many fences that I used this method and as I said it worked well.

Comment: @EdBeal   If the hole is full of water, how do you measure the water?  How do you control the water-cement ratio?

Comment: The mix displaces the water its a post not a structural member some water in the hole works better than trying to add water after the mix is in the hole especially with clay.

Comment: @EdBeal  Hmmm...with clay?  I'm lost...

Comment: Clay soil you really have to pre mix or dump some water in first. Putting a gallon in on top as instructions state really won't work. Had to move a fence many years back the owners had me put it several feet on the neighbors land over 6 months later many of the posts had not worked well although it was easy to break the middle section off not the bottom and top.

Comment: @EdBeal   Hmmm...I see...

Comment: Regular Portland cement has been called "hydraulic cement " because it will cure under water.

Comment: The reason adding cement to water in a hole works better than adding water to cement is the cement will sink in the water and is easier to mix & wet all the way through.  Pouring water on dry cement may not penetrate completely, leaving pockets of dry powder.  Doing this in clay soil holds the water better for mixing, compared to loose porous soil.  Be careful though, concrete is strongest when mixed a little dry.  Using too much water (eg. wet and sloppy) makes the concrete weaker. Mixing the concrete out of the hole gives better control over the final mix.